# Specifying the font for only one character with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm using `XeTeX` and the `fontspec` and `unicode-math` packages. In order to use a different math font for Greek letters, I do something like this, using the `range` option of `\setmathfont`:

```
\setmathfont[Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/]{texgyretermes-math.otf} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek},Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
```

Now, how could I change the font for only one Greek letter (say `\phi`) ?

### Update

Based on @egreg's answer (which is deleted now), I tried the following code. The `$\phi$` does not appear in the output. If I replace this line by the commented line, then $\phi$ appears in the output but it is not in regular font.

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/,Scale = 1.05]{FreeMonoBold.ttf} 
\setmainfont
[        Scale = 1.1,
     Extension = .otf,
   UprightFont = *-regular,
      BoldFont = *-bold,
    ItalicFont = *-italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
]{xits}

\setmathfont[Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/]{texgyretermes-math.otf} 
\setmathfont[range={\mitvarphi,\mitphi},Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{varphi,phi},Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyretermes-regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int,Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/]{texgyretermes-math.otf}

\begin{document}

$\phi = \psi+1$. 

\end{document}
```

### Second update

Since I use only three greek letters in my document, `phi`, `mu` and `lambda`, the following code works :

```
\setmathfont[Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/]{texgyretermes-math.otf} 
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek},Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyretermes-regular.otf} 
\setmathfont[range={\mitmu,\mitlambda},Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math/]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
```

Comment: TeX Gyre Termes is not a math font, so it has no `\mitphi` and `\mitvarphi`.

Comment: @egreg And why that does not work with the commented line instead ?

Comment: @egreg I also tried `range=\mathit/{"03D5}`

Comment: It's not at all clear what your aim is.

Comment: @egreg : I want the *converse* of your output : only $\phi$ in regular font, not the other Greek letters. I have just posted a working solution, but it requires to list all the other Greek letters.

Comment: Just a comment, you don't need to put in the `Path` for fonts installed in the texmf free. Also, this question is about `unicode-math`, not `fontspec`. But is this a question any more?

Comment: @WillRobertson My solution consists in setting all the greek letters in regular font whereas I want only one. Then I set the other greek letters appearing in my paper to the math font. The question is about the more natural solution : how to directly set the font for a unique greek letter  ?

Comment: Exactly as you've written: `\setmathfont[range={\mitmu}]...` But perhaps I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @WillRobertson I want **only** `phi` in regular font. Imagine I use many Greek letters in my document. Using my solution, I should type `range={\mitmu,\mitlambda,\mittheta,\mitalpha,\mitbeta,\mitgamma...`. This is not a serious solution !

Comment: @WillRobertson That sounds a stupid solution because the only thing I need is something like `\renewcomand{\phi}{????}`.

Comment: @WillRobertson Another attempt to explain : I want that **all** Greek letters have their **usual** rendering **except** `\phi`. My solution firstly replaces the usual rendering of all Greek letters, and then it set all Greek letters except `phi` back to their usual rendering, by manually typing each of them. Instead of replacing the rendering of `phi` such as a `renewcommand` would do !

Comment: Note that `amsfonts` and `amssymb` are redundant if you use `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 2):

In normal text, `phi` is only one glyph, and the font makes it upright, bold, italic, bold-italic. In math text, there are a dozen `phi` glyphs, and the boldness, italic is part of the glyph itself:

[image: phi math]

To have upright lower case Greek, use `\setmathfont{Asana Math}[math-style=french]`, for example, and use `\mitphi` for italic phi.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[math-style=french,Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[range={\mitphi},Colour=red]
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}
abc xyz 
$
\mupphi
\mupvarphi
\mbfphi
\mbfvarphi
\mitvarphi
\mitphi
\mbfitvarphi
\mbfitphi
\mbfsansvarphi
\mbfsansphi
\mbfitsansvarphi
\mbfitsansphi
$

$\phi \mu \lambda$
\end{document}
```

Use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\mupphi{\mitphi}}` to redefine upright phi as italic phi.

[image: mupphi redefined]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[math-style=french,Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[range={\mitphi},Colour=red]
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\mupphi{\mitphi}}

\begin{document}
phi $\phi$, upright phi (now italic) $ \mupphi$, and the rest $ \mu \lambda$
\end{document}
```

To do the converse, italic lower case Greek with italic phi redefined as upright phi:

[image: phi 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[range={\mupphi},Colour=red]
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\mitphi{\mupphi}}

\begin{document}
phi $\phi$, italic phi (now upright) $ \mitphi$, and the rest $ \mu \lambda$
\end{document}
```

Or maybe even just use `\mupphi` wherever needed.