# How this combination of fonts is even possible?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have been recently reading an article in Nature Reviews Chemistry and was impressed by the beauty of typography. Let me show you a small fragment of text involving some mathematical formulas.

[image]

I indicated different fonts with colors. As you can see, STIX is mixed with Minion Pro and with Diverda, but the mixture looks very natural and balanced. Without inspecting properties of PDF I would have never guessed that there are so many fonts here. How is it even possible? I know that `unicode-math`supports `Minion Math` (proprietary OpenType font), `Cambria Math`, `STIX`, but what about `Diverda`? Obviously it lacks greek letters and therefore `Minion Pro Italic` is used. But how? Can someone reproduce this beautiful excerpt with `XeLaTex`? I managed to can close to it by using `Minion Pro` for text and `Cambria Math` for equations, but it is not even nearly the same.

### Edit

Based on the 2 answers below, I would like to provide a working example and describe what exactly is my problem.

Consider this starting point

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} % space for binding
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{5cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% -- text font --
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Diverda Sans Com Light}[
  BoldFont =Diverda Sans Com Medium
]

% -- math fonts --
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=body]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=box]

% -- frame --
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Carrara}{HTML}{EEEDEA}
\mdfdefinestyle{refa}{linecolor=Carrara!50!black,
  backgroundcolor=Carrara,roundcorner=5pt,leftmargin=2cm,%
  topline = false,bottomline=false,leftline=false,rightline=false,%
  frametitlerule=true,frametitlerulewidth=0.5pt,%
  font=\sffamily\footnotesize,frametitle={Box}, frametitlefont=\footnotesize\bfseries\sffamily,%
  }

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%===============================================
 \mathversion{body}
\lipsum[1][1-2] $W(\omega,t)/v_q+\symbf{\Sigma}(z_1,z_3)\otimes\symbf{G}(z_3,z_2)$, \lipsum[1][4-5]
$\hat{H}_p\equiv \symbf{\nabla}_p$, \lipsum[1][6-7].

\begin{mdframed}[style=refa]
   \mathversion{box}
  \lipsum[2][1-3] $\phi$ that is, $\mathversion{box}\Psi\approx\psi\otimes\phi$. \lipsum[2][4-5]
\begin{align}
  i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t)=\hat{H}_p(t)\psi(t)
\end{align}
\lipsum[3][1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

yielding
[image]

It has the following characteristics:

- Body text - Minion Pro Body equations
- Cambria Math Box text
- Diverda Sans Com Light Box equations
- STIX Two Math

Let us say, I am happy with the body, but I want to change the math in the box. Why? Well, heavy STIX does not match light Diverda. But Diverda does not have greeks, therefore, let us use Minion Pro for them. The mathfonts are defined therefore as

```
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=body]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=box]
\setmathfont{Minion Pro Italic}[range=it/{Greek,greek},version=box]
\setmathfont{Diverda Sans Com Light Italic}[range=it/{latin, Latin},version=box]
```

with this result

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Why the body math font has changed? Why some characters are missing in the box?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254076/specifying-the-font-for-only-one-character-with-unicode-math, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365509/replacing-single-codepoints-in-unicode-math-with-luatex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228735/make-specific-math-symbols-heavier etc.

Comment: xetex and luatex can use any opentype font you have on the system you can load as many as you need. It is not clear exactly what your question is?

Comment: Oh boy, the third line looks like `a r e  f u r t h e r  s i m p l i fi e d  a n d  r e d u c e d  t o`, this is a sign that the original is not prepared by TeX `:)`

Comment: Why not the maths fonts from the MinionPro package? They would match Minion Pro for text perfectly.

Comment: @RuixiZhang -- *Nature* publications are *not* prepared with TeX.  I had an opportunity to talk with Paul Barnes, one of the principals of the firm that developed the new fonts for *Nature*.  He said that, although LaTeX submissions are accepted, the production flow has several steps with archival files being stored as XML, and the final output "flowed through InDesign".  (This information appears in my column in TUGboat 41:1, and was cleared by Barnes.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton But can InDesign deal with math? I am often using Adobe Illustrator, but TeX is indispensable for math.

Comment: I've been given to understand that there is a plugin for math.  I suspect it's based on TeX, but have no firsthand knowledge.  (I didn't ask about that, and Barnes isn't the math-knowledgeable partner in the firm.)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried, from one hour, differents options: in this moment the best is for my opinion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
If we make a mean-field
\[ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t)=\hat{H}_p(t)\psi(t)\]
\end{document}
```

You could to try for the text `%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}` and for the math-style

```
%\setmathfont{XITS Math} or
%\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
```

[image]

Here there is a combination only of Libertinus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
If we make a mean-field
\[ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(t)=\hat{H}_p(t)\psi(t)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a nice idea. I am curious to compare on the bigger piece of text.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have all of those fonts on my system to test, but you could get something like this with the combination

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Diverda Sans Com}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range=it/{Greek,greek}]{Minion Pro italic}
% Similarly for range=up, bfup, bfit, Latin or digits as desired.
```

Then define your sidebox to use `\sffamily` and change colors with `xcolor`.

Comment: I am agree totally with you. I have given an answer with the disponible fonts.

Comment: But there is a problem though, since we declare Diverda as the sans serif font for text, it is also natural to have Diverda Sans Com Light Italic for the majority of symbols in the formula (see OP). But I have to admit that your solutionwith STIX  looks beautiful. Except I want almost serifless math.

Comment: @yarchik I was trying to duplicate the selections in the example you gave, but that’s possible too. You would want to `\setmathfont{Fira Math}` for sans-serif math or `\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}` for very subtle serifs. Then you could define `\setmathfont[range=it/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}]{Diverda Sans Com Light Italic}` to use its letters in math mode, and similarly for `up`, `bfup` and `bfit`.

Comment: If Diverda doesn’t have Greek (I don’t know one way or the other), just remove `greek` and `Greek` from that example.

Comment: I've tried, but `Package fontspec Warning: Font "Diverda Sans Com Light Italic" does not contain requested Script "Math".`

Comment: I will install "Fira Math"  and "GFS" to give a try. Can it be that `mathspec`, not the `unicode-math` is the way to go?

Comment: @yarchik Both Fira Math and GFS Neohellenic Math are on CTAN and part of the TeX Live distribution, so you might not need to do anything to install them.

Comment: The `mathspec` package is designed for using a modern text font family together with legacy math fonts. Its syntax for substituting in letters from another font is simpler. Maybe I should propose this as a QoL feature for `unicode-math`?

Comment: Right, this may be a good idea.